# Importance of break in a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Please does anyone know the benefit of breaking a loop before it finishes execution. why not just set the condition to terminate at the point at which you set the break condition. for instance,

instead of this:

```
for(let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    if (i == 6) break;
    console.log(i);
}
```

why not just do this ?:

```
for(let i = 1; i <6; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: Breaking a loop is usually useful when you need to stop execution for design reasons, your example doesn't really make much sense, since it's not a "real" scenario. Think about a scenario where you're validating 1000 records: if the first one fails the validation, why would you ever validate the remaining 999 when you can stop the execution after the first one?

Comment: Like when you are searching for some data in an array, when you get it you would not want to continue searching so break the loop. Obviously, there are better ways to do so but just a scenario.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only terminate the loop with the `for` loop declaration condition at the very beginning of the loop. Using `break` gives you more flexibility, allowing you to terminate anywhere in the body of the loop. For example:

```
const arr = [ ... ];
let firstValidItem;
for(let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    const item = arr[i];
    if (itemIsValid(item)) {
        firstValidItem = item;
        break;
    }
    invalidItems.push(item);
}
```

Sure, sometimes you can put all the logic necessary into the for loop declaration, but that's not *always* the case. In those other cases, `break` is a useful option to have.

Answer (score 0):

The break statement has the following two usages:

- When the break statement is encountered inside a loop, the loop is
  immediately terminated and the program control resumes at the next
  statement following the loop.
- It can be used to terminate a case in the switch statement.

**Example:**

```
public class Test {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      int [] numbers = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};

      for(int x : numbers ) {
         if( x == 30 ) {
            break;
         }
         System.out.print( x );
         System.out.print("\n");
      }
   }
}
```